# Deserializing $ref and $id

Tags: json, serialization, json.net

So I'm trying to deserialize an object that has properties: $ref and $id. I have tried going between Dictionary as well as an object where I have specified namingconventions via JsonPropertyAttribute. **Serialization works**, but **deserialization doesn't**. The error I keep getting is:

> Additional text found in JSON string
>   after finishing deserializing object.

Sample code where all three samples, fail.

```
[Serializable]
public class Ref
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "$ref")]
    public virtual string RefName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "$id")]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Child
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(IsReference = true)]
    public virtual Ref Father { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Additional text found in JSON string after finishing deserializing object.
        //Test 1
        var reference = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        reference.Add("$ref", "Persons");
        reference.Add("$id", 1);

        var child = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        child.Add("_id", 2);
        child.Add("Name", "Isabell");
        child.Add("Father", reference);

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(child);
        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json); //Exception

        //Test 2
        var refOrg = new Ref {RefName = "Parents", Id = 1};
        var refSer = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(refOrg);
        var refDeser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Ref>(refSer); //Exception

        //Test 3
        var childOrg = new Child {Father = refOrg, Name = "Isabell"};
        var childSer = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(childOrg);
        var childDeser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Child>(refSer); //Exception
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue when trying to deserialize a swagger/json schema document. The solution is:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore;
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll find that `$ref` & `$id` are special properties used by Json.NET to manage multiple instances of objects in a single object graph.

By putting these keys into your dictionary the deserialize process is trying to parse these as references to objects that don't exist.

Try altering the keys.

Answer (score 0):

This answer worked for me: [Json.Net adding $id to EF objects despite setting PreserveReferencesHandling to "None"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128689/json-net-adding-id-to-ef-objects-despite-setting-preservereferenceshandling-to)

In your implementation of DefaultContractResolver/IContractResolver, add this;

```
public override JsonContract ResolveContract(Type type) {
    var contract = base.ResolveContract(type);
    contract.IsReference = false;
    return contract;
}
```