# Json.Net adding $id to EF objects despite setting PreserveReferencesHandling to "None"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, serialization, json.net

I've already looked at [how to remove $id during JSON serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11542144/how-to-remove-id-during-json-serialization) but the answers given do not seem to be working for me and I hope someone can figure out what I am doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(target, new JsonSerializerSettings {
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include,
    PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.None,
    ContractResolver = new CustomContractResolver(),
    Converters = CustomConverters
});
```

The output from this is still coming out with $id's, BUT, only on Entity Framework objects, is this by design?  If so, is there any way to prevent those $id's on Entity Framework objects?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The custom `ContractResolver` setting overrides the `PreserveReferencesHandling` setting.

In your implementation of `DefaultContractResolver`/`IContractResolver`, add this;

```
public override JsonContract ResolveContract(Type type) {
    var contract = base.ResolveContract(type);
    contract.IsReference = false;
    return contract;
}
```

This behaves similarly to the `PreserveReferencesHandling.None` setting without a custom `ContractResolver`.