# Web Api json response $id variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

in asp web api i have this controller that respond to ajax request and send back json data:

```
public IEnumerable<PersonaleDTO> GetPersonale()
{
    var n = (from p in db.Personale
             select new PersonaleDTO { Id = p.Id, Nome = p.Nome, Cognome = p.Cognome Cellulare = p.Cellulare, Email = p.Email, Attivo = (bool)p.Attivo }).ToList();
    return n;
}
```

This method return seven object and it's correct.

Now when i receive back the data in the json format i see that i receive also and $id member along with the id, Nome, Cognome...

What is the $id variable? How can remove this from the json response?

Answer (score 10):

Try this code in `WebApiConfig`

```
var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.None;
```

**Edit :** If for some reason you're using a custom ContractResolver then as per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128689/json-net-adding-id-to-ef-objects-despite-setting-preservereferenceshandling-to)

The custom ContractResolver setting overrides the PreserveReferencesHandling setting.

In your implementation of DefaultContractResolver/IContractResolver, add this;

```
public override JsonContract ResolveContract(Type type) {
    var contract = base.ResolveContract(type);
    contract.IsReference = false;
    return contract;
}
```

This behaves similarly to the PreserveReferencesHandling.None setting without a custom ContractResolver.

Comment: He also asked "What is the $id variable"... Do you have an answer for that?