# Json Deserialize returns null

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize string to `Dictionary<string, dynamic>` object

```
string jsonString = "{\r\n \"$ref\":\"3"\r\n}";
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(jsonString);
```

but I am getting null value for `dict`

I have tested it against more complex strings and it worked fine.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Try with `string jsonString = "{\r\n \"ref\":\"3\"\r\n}";` :)

Comment: thanks but I need that exact value, how can i get it

Comment: As you can see from the [JSON.NET documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PreserveObjectReferences.htm), `$ref` is handled specially.  [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397511/deserializing-ref-and-id) has answers that might help.