# Deserialize meta $id to ID property

Tags: json.net

The JSON.NET deserializer recognizes a property named `$id`, and internally uses this property's value to identify the object.  The server-side of my app populates these properties with unique values that are meaningful to the app.  The POCOs on my app's client all have `string ID` properties.

How do I configure JSON.NET such that, upon deserialization, the `$id` values will be stored in the POCOs' `string ID` properties?

Comment: Did you try [Deserializing $ref and $id](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397511/3744182)?  Or do you want to deserialize `"$id"` properties while still [preserving object references](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PreserveObjectReferences.htm)?

Comment: And also [Can not deserialize JSON containing $ref keys](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22299390/3744182).

Comment: @dbc I haven't tried `[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "$id")]` since those links say it won't work. I've configured JSON.NET to use `$id` for preserving object references, and need it to continue doing so.

Comment: The answers to those question say that you can use `[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "$id")]` as long as you also set `MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore`. But if you need to both preserve references and capture the `"$id"` into an object property, those answers might not work for you.  Can you share a [mcve]?